# Extract Reality Composer scene for ARQuickLook

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I have a `Reality Composer` scene and I want to extract it as `usdz` file or any files that can be used in `ARQuickLook`?
is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's [Creating 3D Content with Reality Composer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_3d_content_with_reality_composer)
document:

> You can also save your composition to a **.reality** file for use as a
> lightweight **AR Quick Look** experience in your app or on the web. This
> allows users to place and preview content in the real world to get a
> quick sense of what it’s like.
>
> To create a Reality file, choose **File > Export > Export Project** in the
> Reality Composer menu, and provide a name for the file. You use the
> Reality file that gets stored to disk just like you would use a **USDZ**
> file, as described in [Previewing a Model with AR Quick Look](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/previewing_a_model_with_ar_quick_look).

Comment: Oh, again my bad, I've tried that, because I've read the Apple article that you mentioned, I just realised it was on a wrong phone (not iOS 13) since it's only supported on iOS 13. Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between a USDZ file and a .reality file? Is there anything a .reality file can do that can't be done with USDZ?

Answer (score 2):

At build time, Xcode compiles your `.rcproject` into a `.reality` file, and AR Quick Look accepts preview items of type `.reality`. Here's an example that uses AR Quick Look to preview the `Experience.rcproject` taken from Apple's [SwiftStrike TableTop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_a_game_with_reality_composer) sample code:

```
import UIKit
import QuickLook
import ARKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let previewController = QLPreviewController()
        previewController.dataSource = self
        present(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int { return 1 }

    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Experience", ofType: "reality") else { fatalError("couldn't find the rcproject file.") }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let item = ARQuickLookPreviewItem(fileAt: url)
        return item
    }    
}
```