# Is model selection & customization in AR Quick Look possible?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, arquicklook

Currently AR Quick Look allows loading 1 usdz or 1 reality file.

Is there any existing / planned functionality that would allow within AR Quick Look:

1. customization of the loaded model (i.e. changing the textures)
2. selection from a collection of (i.e. 10) models without packing all of them at once in 1 reality file

As reference there is this new functionality of Google Scene Viewer showing a collection of animals you can select:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't change model's texture via ARQuickLook (as the name of framework implies) but you can definitely select files from collection.

For implementing a collection for ARQuickLook use the following instance method:

```
func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {  
    return 10
}
```

This method is used when Quick Look preview controller needs to know the number of preview items to include in the preview navigation list.

If you wanna know how your code might look like, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539227/extract-reality-composer-scene-for-arquicklook/56550741) post.

Comment: any pointers on how to select files form a collection? Once you open a model in AR (so you can place the model in the room) there is no other functionality than the bottom banner afaik

Comment: @Andy Jazz, Can you please check my question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078882/change-ar-model-usdz-in-quicklook